# In which denominations do people consider Mary, mother of Jesus, to be the "Second Eve"?

Tags: denomination-survey, virgin-mary, mariology

I was reading DK Publishing's [The Illustrated Bible Story By Story](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756689627). The authors claim to be biblical scholars, historians, and pastors, which may give a Christian slant to the Bible, even though the audience, as they claim in the book, is for everyone, Christian and non-Christian alike. The authors love to use weasel words, such as "some biblical scholars think..." or "Christians believe..." without really pointing out which denomination actually believes that doctrine. They claim, for instance, that Mary, mother of Jesus, is *more than just a mother of a child on Christmas cards*. Mary is the new Eve, but unlike the first Eve during the Creation, Mary is obedient to God and suffers silently, because she has to deal with the social stigma of bearing a child out-of-wedlock. They even cite Isaiah to support the notion that a *virgin* would give birth, which may be interpreted as foreshadowing of the virgin birth of Jesus Christ. As Jesus grows up, she becomes her son's disciple. It is said that she will be called "blessed" by all successive generations because of her son Jesus, and through her, people will achieve eternal life, whereas Eve denies humanity eternal life.

I wish to know how many denominations actually believe that Mary is regarded as the Second Eve (like how Jesus is regarded as the Second Adam). The authors of the book seem to evade the denominational issue, treating Christianity as one whole group.

Comment: I see numerous references to this idea in (Roman) Catholicism (if that counts as a denomination). Google doesn't turn up a hit on this idea (for me) that isn't Catholic. It seems a lot of what Catholicism teaches about Mary stem from the need for her to be sinless (at least until Jesus' birth), because otherwise Jesus would have inherited a sinful nature and not been perfect and sinless. (I apologize to adherents to this idea if my summary is inaccurate—it's not an answer to the question.)

Comment: I have heard a Catholic teaching that Mary had to be pure to contain Jesus. As far as other denominations I do not know. I know that God uses a lot of symbolism, and wearing a crown of thorns (John 19:2). Was symbolic to being surrounded by annoyance. And also the enemies are in the house comment (Matt 10:36). And his public announcement that others were his Mother (Matthew 12:46-50). Deduct for yourselves, but it does say these things.

Answer (score 1):

In Coptic Orthodox text (not sure about other Orthodox Christians), Mary the Mother of Jesus is referred to as the "Second Eve". A quick Google search brought me to this [link](http://lacopts.org/orthodoxy/our-faith/the-holy-virgin-mary/on-the-apparitions-of-st-mary-in-egypt/)

> He is the Lover of mankind; she loves her each of children. He is our Father of all; she is the Lady of us all. He is the Good Shepherd; she is the blessed mother. He is the Bridegroom; she, the pure and blessed bride. He is the Light of the world; she is the mother of the true Light. He is the Second Adam and the Firstborn of all creation; she is the **Second Eve** and the pride of our race. He is the Alpha and Omega; She is the Ever-virgin. He is the Holy One; She is the Panagia. We worship You, O Christ; we magnify you, the holy Theotokos.